# Cannot export xml opened with excel to xml

Tags: xml, excel

I have a website form that I exported as XML that I'd like to do a large number of changes that involve duplicating some (not all) content.
If I open the XML with MS Excel, it opens in Table view which is perfect for me to dump data into the columns from a CSV and duplicate the other cells in the row.

The problem is that I wish to save it in the original XML format (so I can import back into my website as a form), but I get the error message "Cannot save or export XML data. The XML Maps in this workbook are not exportable".

How can I overcome this problem?

The exported XML original and updated XLSX file are uploaded into the following share: http://sdrv.ms/16kiBgH

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have googled and found this
[how-to](http://www.bitwizards.com/Blogs/Bryan-Soltis/November-2010/How-To-Export-an-Excel-2010-Worksheet-to-XML)

Verify Map for Export gives:
forms_Map is not exportable because it contains:
- List of Lists
- Denormalized data
- A mapped element's relationship with other elements cannot be preserved

Comment: I have the same issue and have seen the data you posted. Problem is that it does nothing to help me understand the issue. It's like a rocket scientist asking a normal person if he has looked at the math for the rocket ship to answer his question. Well, If I could do that, what need would I have for this forum?

Comment: I can't get why it isn't possible to retrieve the XML file after changes if Excel was able to open it as a table in the first place.